# Is there an easy way to convert docker-compose.yml to heroku.yml to run my Dockerfiles on seperate dynos for Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, dyno

I am struggling to work out what I need to do to get this up an running on Heroku.  I normally have a Procfile that has information for Heroku for the Gunicorn app for my Python build.  But as this Dockerfile has 4 containers I am guessing it would need 4 dynos.  How would I edit my Procfile or do I need a heroku.yml?

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend:0.21
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './Docker/Dockerfile.frontend'
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  notification:
    image: notification:0.21
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './Docker/Dockerfile.notification'
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
  user:
    image: user:0.21
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: './Docker/Dockerfile.user'
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"
  stripe:
    image: stripe:0.21
    build:   
      context: .
      dockerfile: './Docker/Dockerfile.stripe'
    ports:
      - "5004:5004"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `heroku.yml` is an option if you have one single Web dyno (accepting HTTP requests) and multiple workers (background processes). [Here](https://github.com/gcatanese/HerokuYmlSample) is an example.

In case you want multiple Web dynos you need to create an Heroku app for each one. There is no support for `docker-compose.yml` so the alternative is to build/push each Dockerfile.
It might sound cumbersome but this can easily be done in CI/CD, check out this [repository](https://github.com/gcatanese/SpringBootService) on Github.